# Is the mean of continuous functions continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ be the space $L^1(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue meausure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let $P$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$. Finally assume $\mathcal{G}\in \mathcal{X}$ is a set of positive continuous functions and assume $P(\mathcal{G})>0$. Define $\bar{P}(B):=P(B \cap \mathcal{G})/P(\mathcal{G})$, for all $B \in \mathcal{X} $,  and the function
$$
\bar{g}(x)= \int_{\mathcal{G}} g(x)d\bar{P}(g), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d.
$$
**QUESTION**
Is $\bar{g}$ a continuous function (on $\mathbb{R}^d$)?

**EDIT** It might be of help to consider a more specific example in applied probability. In statistics sometimes the interest is in estimating the data generating probability density $f_0$, provided that the data are considered as realisations of the random vectors $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, which are assumed independent and identically distributed according to $F_0$, an absolutely continuous (w.r.t. $\lambda$) probability measure with density $f_0$.

Now, it is often assumed that $f_0 \in \mathcal{G}:=\{g_\theta, \, \theta \in \Theta\}$, where $(\Theta, d)$ is a Polish space; denote by $\mathcal{T}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the metric $d$ on $\Theta$. Specifically, it is assumed that $\mathcal{G}$ is a class of functions $g_\theta(x)$ such that:

**a.** for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the map $\theta\mapsto g_\theta(x)$ is $\mathcal{T}$-measurable;

**b.** for each $\theta \in \Theta$, the map $x \mapsto g_\theta(x)$ is measurable w.r.t. to Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{R}^d$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and defines a valid probability density; in our case, we also assume the latter map is coninuous.

In Bayesian statistics, inference is based on the specification of a ''prior'' probability measure $\Pi_\Theta$ on the space $(\Theta,\mathcal{T})$. Denoting by $\mathcal{L}^1$ the sub-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{G}$, there exists a $\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{L}^1$ measurable map $\phi:\Theta \mapsto \mathcal{G}: \theta \mapsto g_\theta$ and the probability measure $\Pi:= \Pi_\Theta\circ \phi^{-1}$ is induced on $\mathcal{G}$. A regular version of the conditional probability exists and is given by Bayes theorem:
$$
\Pi_n(G):= \frac{\int_G \prod_{i=1}^n g(X_i) d\Pi(g)}{\int_{\mathcal{G}} \prod_{i=1}^n g(X_i) d\Pi(g)}=\frac{\int_{\phi^{-1}(G)} \prod_{i=1}^n g_\theta(X_i) d\Pi_\Theta (\theta)
}{\int_{\Theta} \prod_{i=1}^n g_\theta(X_i) d\Pi_\Theta (\theta)}, \quad G \in \mathcal{L}^1
$$
that is, $\Pi_n$ is a Markov kernel from $(\times_{i=1}^n \mathbb{R}^d, \otimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{R}^d)$ (the sample space) to $(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{L}^1)$. An estimator of $f_0$ is now given by the so-called predictive density
$$
\bar{g}(x):=\int_{\mathcal{G}} g(x) d\Pi_n(g)= \frac{\int_{\Theta} g_\theta(x) \prod_{i=1}^n g_\theta(X_i) d\Pi_\Theta (\theta)
}{\int_{\Theta} \prod_{i=1}^n g_\theta(X_i) d\Pi_\Theta (\theta)}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d,
$$
see e.g. Ch. 6.8.3 in Ghosal and van der Vaart (2017) book

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/fundamentals-of-nonparametric-bayesian-inference/C96325101025D308C9F31F4470DEA2E8.

Since $f_0$, the density to be estimated, is continuous, it is natural to wonder whether its estimator $\bar{g}$ is continuous $F_0^{(n)}$-almost surely, where $F_0^{(n)}$ is the joint probability mesure of $X_1, \ldots,X_n$ on $(\times_{i=1}^n \mathbb{R}^d, \otimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{R}^d)$. An easier question would be: given $X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n$, is
$$
\bar{g}(x):=\int_{\mathcal{G}} g(x) d\Pi_n(g)= \frac{\int_{\Theta} g_\theta(x) \prod_{i=1}^n g_\theta(x_i) d\Pi_\Theta (\theta)
}{\int_{\Theta} \prod_{i=1}^n g_\theta(x_i) d\Pi_\Theta (\theta)}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: I don't think it is even clear (or true) that $\overline{g}(x)$ is well-defined in general (i.e., it could be infinite at some points).

Comment: If you know that the functions in $\mathcal{G}$ are uniformly bounded, then everything is well-defined, and continuity follows via dominated convergence, taking $x_n \to x$.

Comment: I see. Asking for uniform boundedness is quite strong, though. Of course in the trivial case of a finite set $\mathcal{G}=\{g_1, \ldots, g_m\}$ the conclusion should be positive. I was wondering how this extends to countably infinite or uncountable sets. I was thinking to the case of a (possibly uncountable) class of probability density functions $g$, not necessarily assumed uniformly bounded: I've seen that objects like $\bar{g}$ are sometimes considered in probability theory, but well deiniteness and continuity are unclear to me.

Comment: Your set-up is too general.  It should be possible to define $P$ so that $g(x,\omega) = h(\omega) g_{0}$ for some $\bar{P}$-measurable $h$ and a fixed function $g_{0}$, and then it gets back to PhoemueX's comment (is $h$ integrable or not?).  A better question would be more specific about the "objects like $\bar{g}$... sometimes considered in probability theory."

Comment: @PeterMorfe I've tried to consider a more specific example, I hope not too specific in fact. I've tried my best to be rigorous.

Comment: @JackLondon, as in my previous comment, if we take $g_{\theta}(x) = h(\theta) g_{0}(x)$ for some fixed probability density $g_{0}$ and an arbitrary measurable function $h$, then we are back to PhoemueX's comments.